Subpanels in chain at detached buildings, plan review
What I'm doing:
Rebuilding detached garage/workshop. Intend to reuse existing 1" PVC conduit underground, but upgrading from individual circuits to a subpanel. I also built a shed with a subpanel and the conduits are roughed to the garage. Jurisdiction is Los Angeles, CA, which has adopted the 2020 NEC with state and local modifications.
How I intend to do it:
At House

1" PVC male out of main panel, to 1" PVC conduit, to 1" PVC LB, to 6x6x4 PVC junction box in crawl space.
4 AWG copper THHN x3 from 90A breaker in main panel, and 6 AWG ground wire, through conduit to junction box.
2-2-2-4 AL SER cable from PVC junction box in crawl space near main panel, to another 6x6x4 PVC junction box in crawl space near garage conduit ~40ft away.
1-1/4" NM clamp connectors for cable-to-box attachment, with plastic bushing.
SER cable supported by GSE-314 service entrance cable staples under floor joists every 4ft.
3-pole distribution block (Square D 9080LBA361101) for copper to aluminum transition in each PVC box, and Burndy K2A25U lug connector for ground splices.
6x6x4 PVC junction box mounted on crawl space cripple wall, threaded 1" PVC male connector, 1" PVC through wall to LB outside to underground.
Drill and tap 10-32 holes for mounting distribution block and ground connector.
Torque all wire connections to specs.

At Garage

1" PVC from underground to LB to 1" PVC male adapter into back of 6x6x4 metal junction box, which will be flush with the finished wall.
Existing conduit is schedule 40. The LB will be about 1 ft above ground.
2-2-2-4 AL SER cable from junction box into subpanel above in same stud bay.
1-1/4" NM clamp connectors for cable-to-box attachment, with plastic bushing.
3-pole distribution block (Square D) for copper to aluminum transition in each PVC box, and Burndy K2A25U lug connector for ground splices.
Drill and tap 10-32 holes for mounting distribution block and ground connector.
2x4 flat against sheating within 12" of bottom of subpanel, for stapling SER cable.
Subpanel will be flush-mounted indoors, 200A main breaker, 30 space.
6/1 armored cable to 2 8ft ground rods separated by 6ft outdoors.
8/3 W/G NM cable from 40A breaker to 4" metal junction box near shed conduit (~25 ft)
1" PVC to LB to underground to shed.
8 AWG THHN x4 to shed panel (~30 ft).
Wire nuts to connect 8/3 NM conductors to THHN conductors. 12 AWG ground pigtail for box ground.
Branch circuits with receptacles will be GFCI-protected either by breaker or first receptacle.

At Shed (existing)

100A 20-space panel with main breaker
6/1 armored cable to 2 8ft ground rods separated by 6ft outdoors.
1" PVC to LB to threaded male connector into back of panel.
PVC expansion coupling since exposed run is ~5ft.
Exposed PVC is schedule 80.
Receptacles are GFCI-protected.

Questions:

Since the existing conduit is schedule 40 above ground, do I need to break concrete, dig down, cut, and couple with a new schedule 80 riser?
For the run from the house main panel, all conduit will be at least 24" off the ground. Is it still considered subject to physical damage? Should I use schedule 80 PVC or EMT instead of schedule 40 here?
In the garage/workshop, must I use GFCI breakers for any 240v outlets?
Is there any issue with chaining subpanels in this fashion? The shed panel won't be subject to much load.
Any problems with this plan or anything obvious missing?
Anything I could do in a more optimal or less complex manner?


What wires or cable do you intend to run through the 1" underground conduit? This doesn't actually say, and most 2-2-2-4 is too large for 1" schedule 40, much less schedule 80 (thicker walls, same outside diamter, smaller hole in the conduit.) Subject to damage is vague in code, (LAHJ may have a guideline they use) but usually less than 18" underground and less than 7 or 8 feet above ground is considered subject to damage. Even going to 3 AWG copper for the existing 1" conduit seems unlikely to pass.

Why are you switching between copper and aluminum in a run between panels? Why not use aluminum the whole way and save some money? And even better, if (it is not clear, please clarify) if the long runs (e.g., 40 feet from main building to shed) are in conduit, use aluminum wires for the entire run - then you eliminate all the splicing blocks, which will save you more money.

@Ecnerwal Sorry if not clear. I am speccing 4 AWG THHN copper inside the conduits, mostly because the underground conduits are already installed and can't be upsized. I think I could use a 1-1/4" conduit for the house main panel to crawl space leg, and aluminum wire there to save a few bucks.

@manassehkatz-Moving 2 Codidact I am switching between copper and aluminum in between panels simply to use cheaper and easier to install wire where possible. It occurs to me that as the conduit from the main house panel to the crawl space isn't yet installed I can upsize that to 1-1/4" and use 2-2-2-4 AL THHN there. As I understand, I cannot sleeve SER cable as it can't make the turn in an LB? Otherwise I would run the SER cable all the way into the main panel. The underground conduit from house to garage is already in place, as is the underground conduit from the garage to the shed.

@AaronP ...are you in a methane zone perchance?  Also, what's the part number of the distribution block you plan to use?

@ThreePhaseEel The distribution block part # is 9080LBA361101. I checked the map and I am not in a methane zone.

@AaronP -- that distribution block is the wrong part (9080LBA series blocks are component recognized aka Rather Useless to you and me)

@ThreePhaseEel Thanks for pointing that out. Am I correct in understanding that I need a UL Listed block instead?

@AaronP for a field assembled application like yours, indeed you do need that UL listing

You're then limited (with 4 AWG copper) to 85A, assuming 75°C connections. The 90°C column is only useful for derating.

I'm not sure about some of the conduit issues, but:

In the garage/workshop, must I use GFCI breakers for any 240v outlets?

Yes. With some exceptions. In particular, if you install any EVSE (a.k.a., car charger) and you hardwire it then you don't need a GFCI/breaker for that circuit. In general, NEC 2020 requires GFCI for all 120V and 240V receptacles in the garage, though your local jurisdiction may have exceptions.

Is there any issue with chaining subpanels in this fashion? The shed panel won't be subject to much load.

Generally speaking that's fine. But the gold standard is to do a load calculation. Actually a few of them:

Entire utility service
Each panel, including any subpanel feeds. Or alternatively, excluding any subpanel feeds and you can subtract to figure out what you have left for the subpanel.

You can, and probably should, overbuild a bit. For example, you may want to use more 2/2/2/4 aluminum wire from garage to shed so that you are not forever stuck at the 8 AWG copper NM limit of 40A. Note that 8 AWG copper wire gets you to 50A. But for a comparable price you can put in more of the aluminum and go up to 90A, load calculation permitting.
